# How to pass a command line switch to XCode when I start 'Build and Debug'

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a XCode project and I can 'build and debug' with it.
But how can I pass a 'command line switch' so that XCode to invoke with that command line switch when I 'build and debug'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In the executables group, you can get info for the executable and set arguments and environment variables in the Arguments tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass extra compiler flags to the compiler, open up your Project Settings, find the setting named **Other C Flags**, and add your desired compiler switches.